# External Hard Drive not found by fdisk

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, kubuntu

My "WD My Passport" External hard drive is not mounting. `sudo fdisk -l` does not show the drive.

`dmesg` gives the following output:

```
[64560.184030] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[64560.372783] ready
[64592.952029] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[64624.366921] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953458176 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/931 GiB)
[64624.367914] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[64624.367916] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[64624.369787] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[64624.369793] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[64624.645424]  sdb: sdb1
[64624.648531] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[64654.060560] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[64654.060568] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 6f 65 58 00 00 08 00
[64654.060571] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953457496
[64654.060770] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[64654.061549] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[64654.061558] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdb] killing request
[64654.061575] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdb] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[64654.061579] scsi 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10) 28 00 74 6f 65 58 00 00 08 00
[64654.061580] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953457496
[64654.061585] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 244182187, async page read
[66245.232030] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[66245.421190] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=259f
[66245.421193] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[66245.421195] usb 2-1.1: Product: My Passport 259F
[66245.421197] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[66245.421198] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: 57583731413136325A305533
[66245.421890] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[66245.432036] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
[66246.460716] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 259F 1004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[66246.461202] scsi 6:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1004 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[66246.465432] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[66246.465513] ses 6:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[66246.465576] ses 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 13
[66254.467465] ses 6:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[66254.467472] ses 6:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[66254.470073] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
```

and `lsusb` gives the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 1058:259f Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It is the first one on the list.

I can't get it to mount on my Windows machine either. Is there a way I can mount it or at least recover the data?

Comment: If not usable in Windows, the drive is likely to be defective. You may try file recovery tools but it may not work. It's as simple as that.